# Tailwind jit compiler error when running "npm run dev"

Tags: jit, tailwind-css, laravel-mix

I'm trying to run "npm run dev," but it gives me an error in the end.
I'm using Laravel Mix and Tailwind CSS.

**Versions**

- laravel-mix: **6.0.22**
- tailwind-css: **^2.0.4**
- @tailwindcss/jit: **^0.1.18**,

**resources/css/app.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [
        require('@tailwindcss/jit'),
    ])
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    purge: ['./resources/**/*.{js,vue,blade.php,css}'],
  darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
       }
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
  ],
}
```

> ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js): TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'theme' of undefined
> at _default (/var/www/work/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/substituteScreenAtRules.js:16:5)
> at /var/www/work/node_modules/@tailwindcss/jit/src/index.js:50:11
> at LazyResult.runOnRoot (/var/www/work/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:339:16)
> at LazyResult.runAsync (/var/www/work/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:391:26)
> at async Object.loader (/var/www/work/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:87:14)
> at processResult (/var/www/work/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:701:19)
> at /var/www/work/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:807:5
> at /var/www/work/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
> at /var/www/work/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
> at context.callback (/var/www/work/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
> at Object.loader (/var/www/work/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:96:7)
>
> 1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp.
> '--stats-children' for more details) webpack compiled with 2 errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enable [just-in-time](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode) mode, set the mode option to 'jit' in your tailwind.config.js file.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: ['./resources/**/*.{js,vue,blade.php,css}'],
    theme: {
        extend: {}
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

But first, you will need to upgrade your Tailwind and related packages, so run the following.

```
npm install -D laravel-mix@latest tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

Also, you'll need to remove the JIT package from your Webpack config and require Tailwind. As of Tailwind CSS v2.1 @tailwindcss/jit has been merged with the core Tailwind CSS repository.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I ask if tailwind css **2.0.4** versions doesn't support **@tailwindcss/jit** now? Because awhile ago, I didn't get such an error. I got this error after upgrading tailwindcss to 2.2 and although I tried to downgrade the tailwindcss to 2.0.4, I still got that error.

Comment: @ZawLinTun I'm not sure, TBH. But without Tailwind 2.1+, you'd be missing out on a lot of new features anyway. I try and keep Tailwind updated to the latest to take advantage of them.